# Angular material how to integrate with coreui template

Tags: angular, angular-material, core-ui

I installed material and imported in app.module.ts and in style.scs imported link even though css not working please help me how can I overcome this problem

Comment: What is your actual problem ? Does it give any error?

Comment: its not giving any error bit css not working